# MySQL server has gone away ConnectionResetError 10054 Flask SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, azure, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a flask rest api app with the following setup.

Packages installed

```
alembic==1.3.0
aniso8601==8.0.0
astroid==2.3.3
attrs==19.3.0
bcrypt==3.1.7
cffi==1.13.2
Click==7.0
colorama==0.4.1
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-Migrate==2.5.2
flask-restplus==0.13.0
Flask-Script==2.0.6
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
Flask-Testing==0.7.1
importlib-metadata==0.23
isort==4.3.21
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.3
jsonschema==3.1.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
Mako==1.1.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
more-itertools==7.2.0
mysqlclient==1.4.5
pycparser==2.19
PyJWT==1.7.1
pylint==2.4.3
PyMySQL==0.9.3
pyrsistent==0.15.5
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-editor==1.0.4
pytz==2019.3
six==1.13.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.11
Werkzeug==0.16.0
wrapt==1.11.2
zipp==0.6.0
```

I have following production config with debug enabled to true to know stack trace.

```
class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True
    user = 'xxxxxx@xxxxxx-mysqldbserver'
    passs = 'xxxxxx'
    host = 'xxxxxx-mysqldbserver.mysql.database.azure.com'
    db = 'ifsc'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://{0}:{1}@{2}/{3}'.format(user, passs, host, db)
```

I have `__init__.py` that initializes SQLAlchemy as follows

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt

from .config import config_by_name

db = SQLAlchemy()
flask_bcrypt = Bcrypt()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_by_name[config_name])
    db.init_app(app)
    flask_bcrypt.init_app(app)
    return app
```

I have an app.py with the following code that actually runs the flask app.
app.py

```
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from api import blueprint

from api.main import create_app, db
from api.main.seed import seed_db

app = create_app(os.getenv('BOILERPLATE_ENV') or 'prod') # dev|prod
CORS(app)
app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
app.app_context().push()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**Problem:** I'm facing the mysql connection issues with the following error on azure's db. I've tried setting `max_allowed_packet` server parameter to `1073741824`. But still see this error.

**Symptoms:** For the fresh deployment, It responds and if the API is left idle for 5 to 10 mins and make the same request, it behaves with the following error. Again it starts working after 60 mins and the behavior continues.

**Stack Trace:**

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError:
>   (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2006, "MySQL server has gone away
>   (ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly
>   closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))") [SQL: SELECT
>   bank_details.id AS bank_details_id, bank_details.bank AS
>   bank_details_bank, bank_details.ifsc AS bank_details_ifsc,
>   bank_details.branch AS bank_details_branch, bank_details.address AS
>   bank_details_address, bank_details.district AS bank_details_district,
>   bank_details.city AS bank_details_city, bank_details.state AS
>   bank_details_state, bank_details.phone AS bank_details_phone,
>   bank_details.micr AS bank_details_micr, bank_details.pin AS
>   bank_details_pin  FROM bank_details  WHERE bank_details.bank =
>   %(bank_1)s AND bank_details.city = %(city_1)s] [parameters: {'bank_1':
>   'axis bank', 'city_1': 'goa'}] (Background on this error at:
>   http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
>   line 713, in _write_bytes self._sock.sendall(data) During handling of
>   the above exception, another exception occurred: File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
>   line 1245, in _execute_context self.dialect.do_execute( File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py",
>   line 581, in do_execute cursor.execute(statement, parameters) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line
>   170, in execute result = self._query(query) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line
>   328, in _query conn.query(q) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
>   line 516, in query self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
>   line 771, in _execute_command self._write_bytes(packet) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
>   line 716, in _write_bytes raise err.OperationalError( The above
>   exception was the direct cause of the following exception: File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2463,
>   in
>   **call** return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response) File "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2449,
>   in wsgi_app response = self.handle_exception(e) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\api.py",
>   line 584, in error_router return original_handler(e) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1866,
>   in handle_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line
>   38, in reraise raise value.with_traceback(tb) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446,
>   in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951,
>   in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\api.py",
>   line 584, in error_router return original_handler(e) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820,
>   in handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line
>   38, in reraise raise value.with_traceback(tb) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949,
>   in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935,
>   in dispatch_request return
>   self.view_functionsrule.endpoint File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\api.py",
>   line 325, in wrapper resp = resource(*args, **kwargs) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\views.py", line 89,
>   in view return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\resource.py",
>   line 44, in dispatch_request resp = meth(*args, **kwargs) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\marshalling.py",
>   line 243, in wrapper resp = f(*args, **kwargs) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\api\main\controller\ifsc_controller.py", line
>   37, in get banks = get_banks_by_name_city(bank, city) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\api\main\service\ifsc_service.py", line 28, in
>   get_banks_by_name_city return Ifsc.query.filter_by(bank = name, city =
>   city).all() File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py",
>   line 3211, in all return list(self) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py",
>   line 3367, in **iter** return self._execute_and_instances(context)
>   File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py",
>   line 3392, in _execute_and_instances result =
>   conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
>   line 982, in execute return meth(self, multiparams, params) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py",
>   line 287, in _execute_on_connection return
>   connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
>   line 1095, in _execute_clauseelement ret = self._execute_context( File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
>   line 1249, in _execute_context self._handle_dbapi_exception( File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
>   line 1476, in _handle_dbapi_exception
>   util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py",
>   line 398, in raise_from_cause reraise(type(exception), exception,
>   tb=exc_tb, cause=cause) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py",
>   line 152, in reraise raise value.with_traceback(tb) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
>   line 1245, in _execute_context self.dialect.do_execute( File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py",
>   line 581, in do_execute cursor.execute(statement, parameters) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line
>   170, in execute result = self._query(query) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line
>   328, in _query conn.query(q) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
>   line 516, in query self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
>   line 771, in _execute_command self._write_bytes(packet) File
>   "E:\sampled\sample_api\env\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
>   line 716, in _write_bytes raise err.OperationalError(
>   sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2006,
>   "MySQL server has gone away (ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054,
>   None))") [SQL: SELECT bank_details.id AS bank_details_id,
>   bank_details.bank AS bank_details_bank, bank_details.ifsc AS
>   bank_details_ifsc, bank_details.branch AS bank_details_branch,
>   bank_details.address AS bank_details_address, bank_details.district AS
>   bank_details_district, bank_details.city AS bank_details_city,
>   bank_details.state AS bank_details_state, bank_details.phone AS
>   bank_details_phone, bank_details.micr AS bank_details_micr,
>   bank_details.pin AS bank_details_pin FROM bank_details WHERE
>   bank_details.bank = %(bank_1)s AND bank_details.city = %(city_1)s]
>   [parameters: {'bank_1': 'axis bank', 'city_1': 'goa'}] (Background on
>   this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8) The debugger caught an
>   exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback
>   which led to the error. To switch between the interactive traceback
>   and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From
>   the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code
>   execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the
>   console icon on the right side.
>
> You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there
>   are some extra helpers available for introspection:
>
> dump() shows all variables in the frame dump(obj) dumps all that's
>   known about the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 4 months of research and understanding how flask works, I made the following change by pushing the app_context to initialize the database resolved the issue.

```
with app.app_context():
    db.init_app(app)
```

**Point to note:**
We must ensure that app context being pushed along with sqlalchemy database initialization. In the posted question, I've been initializing db and then I was pushing the app context later `app.app_context().push()`.

References: [Manually Push a Context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/appcontext/#manually-push-a-context)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL server set these :

MAX_EXECUTION_TIME is used for long running queries.

```
SET SESSION MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=20000;
SET GLOBAL MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=200000;
```

Also set wait_timeout:

```
SET session wait_timeout=30000;
SET @@GLOBAL.wait_timeout=30000;
```

Comment: no luck, still the same error. I wonder how small this requrest is. Generally has 1 to 7 records but still fails.